# Setting up an Ubuntu Server 14.04 Firewall. Can it Protect multiple pc's on a local network?

Tags: firewall

I am new to Ubuntu firewalls. I would like to setup an Ubuntu Firewall on computer #1 it can be connected wirelessly or by Ethernet. I have another ubuntu server running on computer #2 and windows 7 on computer #3. Both computers #2 and #3 are connected to the network by Ethernet.

Is it possible to run incoming/outgoing connections from computers #2 and #3 through the Ubuntu Firewall on computer #1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's perfectly possible. The Linux kernel is great at doing it. But you'll probably need a second network card adapter on the Linux firewall.

You can set up a firewall using the iptables package or use one of the various free firewall managers like Shorewall or UFW.
[or check this review](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/7-of-the-best-linux-firewalls-697177#null)

I think [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-linux-firewall--net-31748) could help you to learn how to setup a firewall on Linux. BTW, since routing and filtering is a Linux kernel feature, all what you can find about Linux firewalling and routing will apply, whatever distro you're using. Wikipedia should have some nice posts too.

Comment: Thanks for the input, though I forgot to mention I will not be using the desktop version just the server command line. Also is there a How to on my question? Because I can't find anything on what I'm trying to do.